# Deleting a widget from a list of widgets [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, widget

In a flutter application that I'm building(a to-do list basically), I wish to delete all the completed tasks(active checkboxes) with a single button.
As of now, it functions as expected ONLY WHEN the last checkbox is active and all the other active checkboxes(if any) are right above it, simultaneously.

The app malfunctions if there is even 1 inactive checkbox after an active checkbox.

Here's the code for the class that creates the task widget :

```
class addnote extends StatefulWidget {

  final String task_txt;
  final int index;// receives the value

  addnote({ Key key, this.task_txt, this.index }): super(key: key);

  @override
  _addnoteState createState() => _addnoteState();
}

class _addnoteState extends State<addnote> {

  bool value=false;
  
  Widget txt_strike(String to_strike, bool str_value){
    return str_value ?
    AutoSizeText(to_strike,style: TextStyle(
      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
      fontFamily: "Quicksand",
      fontSize: 20.0,
      color: Colors.grey,
    ),
    maxLines: 2,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    )
        :
    AutoSizeText(to_strike,style: TextStyle(
      //decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
      fontFamily: "Quicksand",
      fontSize: 20.0,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    maxLines: 2,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
        color:Colors.grey,
        offset: Offset(-6.0,4.0),
        blurRadius: 4.0,
        )],
            color: Colors.white
        ),
         margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0,horizontal: 3.0),
      child:InkWell(

        onTap: (){setState(() {
          value=!value;
          w_checks[widget.index]=!w_checks[widget.index];
        });},
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(flex:1,
              child: CircularCheckBox(
                  disabledColor: Colors.white,
                  activeColor: Colors.green,
                  value: value,
                  onChanged:(bool _changed)
                  {
                    // print(w_checks[Index]);
                    setState(() {
                      value=!value;
                      w_checks[widget.index]=!w_checks[widget.index];
                    });
                  }),
            ),
            Expanded(flex:5,
                child: txt_strike(widget.task_txt, value)),
           ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the code for the func that deletes the task widget :

```
void del_task(){
   int count=0;
   for(int i=0; i<w_checks.length; i++)
   {
     if(w_checks[i]==true)
       count++;
   }
   while(count>=0)
   {
     for(int j=0; j<w_checks.length; j++)
     {
       if(w_checks[j]==true)
       {
         setState(() {
           { w_tasks.removeAt(j);  //w_tasks is the list of all the tasks
           w_checks.removeAt(j);   //w_checks is the list that stores bool values corresponding to each checkbox
           }
         });
         for(int k=j; k<w_checks.length; k++)
           {
             w_tasks[k]=w_tasks[k+1];
             w_checks[k]=w_checks[k+1];

           }
         break;
       }
     }
     count--;
   }
 }
```

Hope I was able to describe my problem, kindly help.

Comment: something like this: `List<String> numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
numbers.removeWhere((item) => item.length == 3);
print(numbers); // [three, four']`

Comment: @pskink yeah I know that method, but I haven't tried to use that here yet. I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really shure about what are you doing inside `del_task()` but I think your problem is caused by the for cycle in which you are moving all later objects down by one position.

That operation is already performed by the "list.removeAt(index)" method, as u can see from the documentation: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/List/removeAt.html

I would have changed the code like this:

```
void del_task(){
   for(int i=0; i<w_checks.length; i++)
   {
       if(w_checks[i]==true)
       {
         setState(() {
           w_tasks.removeAt(i);  
           w_checks.removeAt(i);   
         });
         i--;
       }
   }
 }
```

I don't understand why you needed the `count` variable.

The code I posted should iterate throught `w_checks`.
When it found a "true" value, it will call `removeAt(i)` and then decrease index by one.

Comment: Okay, so I got confused by the way deletion occurs in list. I thought the .removeAt(ind) doesn't shift the elements, so I created a piece of code to shift the elements by one position.
Also, the 'count' var counts the number of elements to be deleted from the list, and it won't be needed anymore, since elements are shifted automatically after every deletion.

Comment: I tried your code, the problem still persists. Would you please have a look at the class that creates the widget ? maybe some changes are required there, I just can't figure out.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your code in a project right now, I'll tell you as soon as I can

Comment: I can't replicate your code in my app. I don't think is related to the class which create the widget.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that either it's the del_task() or the class that creates widget,  because everything else seems just fine

Comment: Please consider upvoting my answer if you think I helped. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't help, else I would've upvoted it right away. Also, I feel that the widget building class needs to be notified everytime a task is deleted, so maybe the problem lies there.

Comment: Then you need to store w_tasks inside the widget building class. By doing so, you'll be able to notify that class in the moment you call "setState()".

Comment: There is a main class that lies above the widget building class, use of w_tasks is more there as compared to the widget building class. So moving it there won't fix it. Also, I'm somewhat getting the idea about the approach, I'll let you know when I get it. If you want to see the complete code, let me know.